# How to make TS automatically infer type arguments on mapped types?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code ([Playground](http://t.ly/6DJw)):

```js
type Either<E, D> = ["error", E] | ["data", D]

type GenericTuple<T = any> = [T, ...T[]];

// [Either<E, D1>, Either<E, D2>, ...] -> Either<E, [D1, D2, ...]>
declare function mergeEithers<E, Ds extends GenericTuple>(
    eithers: { [K in keyof Ds]: Either<E, Ds[K]> }
): Either<E, Ds>;

type MessageError = {message: string};
declare const either1: Either<MessageError, string>
declare const either2: Either<MessageError, number>

// unpacked: Either<unknown, [string, number]>
const unpacked = mergeEithers([either1, either2])
```

How should we write it so TS automatically infers `unpacked` as `Either<MessageError, [string, number]>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) in the type signature of `mergeEithers`.  I find that the compiler isn't always able to extract the desired amount of information in such cases.  You are passing in a value `eithers` of type `{ [K in keyof Ds]: Either<E, Ds[K]> }` and hoping the compiler can infer both `E` and `Ds` from it.  Generally speaking it will be able to do something reasonable with `Ds` (since it's a homomorphic mapping) and probably give up before you get anything useful for `E`.

In cases where this sort of "backwards" inference isn't reliable, I usually go for the brute-force "forwards" inference: if I want the compiler to infer a type `A`, I should pass in a value of type `A`.  To that end, we will have `eithers` be of type `A`, which will tend to be inferred properly.  Then we will use `A` to *compute* the desired output type which used to be called `Either<E, Ds>`:

```
declare function mergeEithers<A extends GenericTuple<Either<any, any>>>(
    eithers: A
): Either<
    Extract<A[number], ["error", any]>[1],
    { [K in keyof A]: Extract<A[K], ["data", any]>[1] }
>;
```

Here I'm using the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to pull out the error and the data parts of the union.  The type `Extract<A[number], ["error", any]>[1]` should be the union of all the possibly-different error types of the `eithers` tuple, while the type `Extract<A[K], ["data", any]>[1]` should be the data type for each element `K` of the `eithers` tuple.

Let's see if it works:

```
const unpacked = mergeEithers([either1, either2])
// const unpacked: Either<MessageError, [string, number]>
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Not terribly pretty, but it works. When using discriminated unions, it's simply `Extract<UnionType, {type: VALUE}>`. Thanks for the answer, the link to the docs and the "forward inference" advice!